# How to Track State Change of Newly Added Values

Tags: react-native

Let's say I have a grocery list where the title of the item, and the quantity is listed. Let's say I found 1 carton of milk, and need 2. So I update the list so that I only need to find one more carton of milk. If I know the contents of the list, I can use state to track each item and re render the list. The issue is, what if I need to add new items. How can I use state to track an unlimited number of newly added values. I've found examples of how to do this but I was wondering what's the most efficient way to do so.

Ex:

```
Eggs 2

Milk 2

Carrots 5
```

Found a milk carton so I update the milk quantity to 1. List is re rendered.

```
Eggs 2 

Milk 1 

Carrots 5
```

But now I add a new value as apples. How do I track apples now? How do I re render it when the value is changed if the state isn't being tracked from the beginning.

```
Eggs 2 

Milk 1 

Carrots 5

Apples 2 <-- How do I track this items state / re render the list when it changes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if data is coming from **API** then you have to refresh or re-call your method after certain time interval. Only you have to make sure that the user is not making any change on in Flat-list(not performing any action on it). here is the sample code to set intervals

```
componentDidMount()
  {
   this._interval = setInterval( () => {this.DataReload()}, 180*1000);  

  } ;

componentWillUnmount()
  {
   clearInterval(this._interval);
  };

 DataReload =()=>{
 //here your code and call you API. update your state data, when the state is changed then your flat-list automatically re-render.
}
```

Comment: The part I'm confused about is the setState itself. How would I go about adding the new values state. For instance would I keep an array of all the states, once I add a new value would I just append a new state into there?

Comment: you just simply overwrite the previous state with the new state. it's automatically re-render the flat-list. if you don't understand how to do that then simply share your code. I'll fix it

Comment: I'm refreshing state data in my project by using  "setInterval". It's very easy.

Comment: I didn't understand how to add new values to track into the setState but now I realize I just had to use a spread operator to copy all the current values and then append the new value to the end. Your answer helped me reach this conclusion so thank you.

Comment: Welcome, @ Sachu